# Access tablet camera from web/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, camera, windows-10

I developing a web based php/mysql/jquery application for a rugged panasonic tablet with windows 10.

And i want to access the camera to take shots.
Tried the html camera web api, usable but no access to flash or default camera functions.

I have two options i think but both not working.

Option one is to use the Panasonic camera program, but can't manage to run the exe from local using php because of shared secure hosting.

Option two is to use the input file upload camera option, but can't get it to work on windows 10.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is possible, but not in the way you're attempting. First, PHP runs on the server, so is not applicable. Secondly, you cannot run an exe from JS - imagine the security implications if that were possible. Thirdly, file input is for uploading files, not accessing live streams. I marked some duplicates which detail some methods you can use to do this - note that they are all in JS as camera access has to be done on the client.